# Ocultar o mostrar información dependiendo del estado de un checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando que, al cambiar el estado de un checkbox, me muestre una información y al no estar el check, no me muestre nada, pero no lo consigo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fantasma').click(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById($(this).attr('rel'));
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

        if($('input[rel="' + rel +'"].fantasma').attr(':checked')){
            $('.contentM').css('display', 'block');
        }else{
            $('.contentM').css('display', 'none');
        }

    });
});
```

y éste es el checkbox:

```
<input  id='bmm" + (i + 1) + "' rel='canvas" + (i + 1) + "' type='checkbox' class='squaredThreex fantasma hh' name='check' value='0'>
```

Comment: ¿La variables `canvas` la ocupas en algún lado? Y en el `if` basta con que uses esta comparación`if($(this).prop("checked") === true)` https://jsfiddle.net/a0z7m3ko/2/

Comment: canvas y el rel si los utilizo por que son varios canvas, pero igual le puse `if($(this).prop("checked") === true)` y no funciono

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu elemento de clase `contentM`?

Comment: `<fieldset rel='canvas" + (i + 1) + " class='ppal contentM' id='content'  style='display: none>` es este

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a0z7m3ko/3/ El código funciona correctamente, tan solo modifiqué la condición `if` Tu consola no te arroja algún error durante la ejecución del evento click?

Comment: Lo que sí es que tuve que modificar tu HTML del fieldset porque te faltó cerrar una apostrofe para el atributo `rel`

Comment: @Javi incluso cuando el código del autor contenga errores, no se debe modificar, ya que eso puede ser parte del error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tu error esta en el evento, no es `click`, es `change` y ademas que es mejor, para tu caso, utilizar la funcion [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) en ves de `.attr()`. te dejo el ejemplo en un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtbmqzf/)

```js
$(function(){
 $('.fantasma').change(function(){
   if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
     $('#dvOcultar').hide();
    }else{
     $('#dvOcultar').show();
    }
  
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cbmostrar">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cbmostrar" class="fantasma" checked />
  Mostrar contenido
</label>
<div id="dvOcultar">
  este texto se ocultara
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo concluir de tu código jQuery lo que quieres saber es si una lista de `input` con el atributo **rel="..."** de la clase "**fantasma**" están tildados (**:checked**) entonces despliegue un contenido sino este contenido lo oculte. De ser esto correcto el código debería ser el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fantasma').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  console.log(rel);
  if($('input[rel="' + rel +'"].fantasma').is(':checked')){
   $('.contentM').css('display', 'block');
  }else{
   $('.contentM').css('display', 'none');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id='bmm" + (i + 1) + "' rel='canvas" + (i + 1) + "' type='checkbox' class='squaredThreex fantasma hh' name='check' value='0'>
<div class="contentM" style="display:none">div de clase contentM</div>
<div class="contentM" style="display:none">otra div de clase contentM</div>
```

Es importante mencionar que el código **html** (tal como lo muestras) intenta ejecutar un código javascript `rel='canvas" + (i + 1) + "'` y literalmente esto no es posible, ocasionara que tu código **jQuery** falle.

Por otro lado, lo que dices querer hacer es otra cosa: "**Si al hacer click en un campo "*checkbox*" este es marcado entonces desplegar el contenido sino  ocultar dicho contenido**", de ser este el caso, entonces el código debería ser el siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fantasma').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $('.contentM').css('display', 'block');
  }else{
   $('.contentM').css('display', 'none');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id='bmm" + (i + 1) + "' rel='canvas" + (i + 1) + "' type='checkbox' class='squaredThreex fantasma hh' name='check' value='0'>
<div class="contentM" style="display:none">div de clase contentM</div>
<div class="contentM" style="display:none">otra div de clase contentM</div>
```

espero estos ejemplos ayuden a aclarar tus ideas, Saludos!! ;))